Experiments carried out to determine the energy of photons of different wavelengths
I imagine it would be very difficult to experimentally determine the energy per photon of monochromatic EM radiation. Since every material reflects/absorbs differently at different wavelengths, I can only see the experimental setup being possible with a black body. Secondly, it is necessary to determine the photon flux (number of photons per time unit).
Have there been any experiments in this direction?

Which experimental setup is it that you are thinking of?


Secondly, it is necessary to determine the photon flux (number of photons per time unit).

Put enough attenuating filters in front of any source and you can reduce its output to the point where you can count the individual photons (given a sensitive enough detector, but this was possible even in the days of detection with chemical films).
Remove the filters to get a strong enough signal to measure the power with a bolometer, knowing that the photon flux is scaled by the attenuation of the filters that were removed.

That's obvious. Thank you. What is missing: Have there been any experiments in this direction?

Actually a half point, but that doesn't exist. :-)

@HolgerFiedler This experiment is so trivial an undergrad instructional lab would be able to do it. I don't know if it's the most accurate way to get the photon energy experimentally, or what practical considerations are needed to get an accurate result. The other thought I had was to find the work function of some metal by some other means and then use a tunable optical source to find the wavelength with corresponding photon energy.

I‘m interested in the experimental evidence.

@HolgerFiedler Why do you suspect that the photons in a monochromatic beam might have different energy than the photons of the same wavelength in blackbody radiation? (In order to understand what kind of experiment you might find convincing)

For example, pass the output of a blackbody radiator through a monochromator, and find the longest wavelength that produces photoemission from a given metal target. Now use a tunable laser to confirm that the longest wavelength that produces photoemission is the same when the source is monochromatic.

Or pass the output of a blackbody source through a monochromator, and use it to measure the responsivity of a given photodiode. Now test the responsivity using a laser of the same wavelength. Since the responsivity strongly depends on the photon energy, getting equal responsivity gives strong evidence the photons have the same energy.
